# Date('now') in PHP

Tags: php

After a long time I needed to use date function of PHP. I wrote something like:

```
echo date('now');
```

and I got the output below:

```
1220123
```

What does that mean ?

Comment: <?php echo date('d=m-Y)'strtotime(now));?>

Comment: What is your requirement???

Comment: Hi Deepu, I just want to know the meaning of the output while using "now" as a parameter in date().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"now" is not a valid parameter for for this expectation, infact it should be strtotime function here, not date.

Date considers your now as

**n**

Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros

**o**

ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

**w**

Numeric representation of the day of the week

Comment: Thanks Hanky panky..for your descriptive answer :)

Answer (score 7):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) :

> - **n**   Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros
> - **o**   ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that
>   year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)
> - **w**   Numeric representation of the day of the week

So, `date("now")` displays 12 (n), 2012 (o) and 3 (w).

You're probably looking for :

- `date("Y-m-d")` for a date
- `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` for a datetime

Comment: Oops sorry Ninsuo i almost posted the same answer, had i seen yours before i wouldnt have submitted

Comment: Thanks Ninsuo for the descriptive information..As Hanky Panky has given answered before you he's deserving acceptance of the answer but I will appriciate by up vote your answer. Thanks a ton..:)

Answer (score 6):

you need to give a valid [format](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to date function (not recognize the 'now' string as meaning of now )

```
$date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

or you can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
$date = new DateTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you consider "now" as a word to get the current date and time, however it would compile on each character. Here is the explanation how it'll compile.

> n = Month in number
>
> o = It considers as a year in ISO-8601.
>
> w = Week in number

So that's why it's returning you the date, year and number of week in a month.

Hope I can explain you bit easily.

Answer (score 0):

"now" is not a valid parameter for [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Correct syntax to print current date in

```
yyyy-mm-dd hours minutes seconds
```

format is as given below

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

also see PHP manual for details of [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: In fact, it _is_ a valid parameter, even if not particularly useful.